# Liferay Startup aborted with message related to version update but I never did the update

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I'm running into a strange behavior with my liferay 6.2 (build 6210). I was trying to install the latest fixpack portal-84 and cannot start my server since. Since I reverted all fixpacks etc. and still the startup doesn't work I doubt the update is the reason. I get the following message `Permission conversion to algorithm 6 has not been completed`. Up until this point the startup looks normal. Strange thing is my database schema was never used for anything else than liferay 6.2.

```
10:42:13,566 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:212] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permission conversion to algorithm 6 has not been completed. Please complete the conversion prior to starting the portal. The conversion process is available in portal versions starting with 5203 and prior to 6200.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permission conversion to algorithm 6 has not been completed. Please complete the conversion prior to starting the portal. The conversion process is available in portal versions starting with 5203 and prior to 6200.
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader._checkPermissionAlgorithm(DBUpgrader.java:297)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:135)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:181)
        at com.liferay.portal.ee.license.StartupAction.doRun(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:74)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1245)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Stopping the server due to unexpected startup errors
```

Is assume that something is wrong within my database (although I have no idea how that happened). When I start liferay with the embedded memory DB the startup works. There are only some other messages in the log because there are lucene files in filesystem without entries in memory db. `select * from RELEASE_;` states the correct version `portal 6210` and my configured database connection is correct as well (tried with jndi resource in tomcat and with conenction information in portal-ext.properties). But maybe there is some other location where a version is saved and is vital to portal startup.

Did anyone ever had this behavior or is this a completely special case that is (more or less) exclusive to me?

Thanks ans regards. Sebastian

Comment: as you're using EE, you should open a support ticket with Liferay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade script checks if the ResourceCode table is empty. It was used prior to Liferay 6, Liferay 6 upgrade scripts usually remove all data from it or the whole table whatsoever.

To overcome this issue I did all the steps according to [this tutorial from Liferay](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/upgrading-liferay?notice=1#migrate-to-algorithm-6). The only difference to your situation is that I'm using Liferay CE.

Comment: As said I did not upgrade liferay. My db schema never served anything else than liferay 6.2. However I still managed to solve the issue. I did some troubleshooting for an liferay 6.0 of mine during the holiday break and had to create some db-synonyms. As intended for 6.2 there is no ResourceCode table within my DB, but liferay still managed to select from this table due to a synonym pointing to the ResourceCode table inside my old liferays database. Dropped the synonym and everything went back to normal.